# Python regex to find functions and params pairs in js files

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-re

I am writing a JavaScript crawler application.
The application needs to open JavaScript files and find some specific code in order to do some stuff with them.
I am using regular expressions to find the code of interest.

Consider the following JavaScript code:

```
let nlabel = rs.length ? st('string1', [st('string2', ctx = 'ctx2')], ctx = 'ctx1') : st('Found {0}', [st(this.param)]);
```

As you can see there is the `st` function which is called three times in the same line. The first two calls have an extra parameter named `ctx` but the third one doesn't have it.

What I need to do is to have 3 `re` matches as below:

**Match 1**

```
Group: function = "st('"
Group: string = "string1"
Group: ctx = "ctx1"
```

**Match 2**

```
Group: function = "st('"
Group: string = "string2"
Group: ctx = "ctx2"
```

**Match 3**

```
Group: function = "st('"
Group: string = "Found {0}"
Group: ctx = (None)
```

I am using the regex101.com to test my patterns and the pattern that gives the closest thing to what I am looking for is the following:

```
(?P<function>st\([\"'])(?P<string>.+?(?=[\"'](\s*,ctx\s*|\s*,\s*)))
```

You can see it in action [here](https://regex101.com/r/Ja1k7H/1/).

However, I have no idea how to make it return the `ctx` group the way I want it.

For your reference I am using the following Python code:

```
matches = []
code = "let nlabel = rs.length ? st('string1', [st('string2', ctx = 'ctx2')], ctx = 'ctx1') : st('Found {0}', [st(this.param)], ctx = 'ctxparam'"
pattern = "(?P<function>st\([\"'])(?P<string>.+?(?=[\"'](\s*,ctx\s*|\s*,\s*)))"
for m in re.compile(pattern).finditer(code):
    fnc = m.group('function')
    msg = m.group('string')
    ctx = m.group('ctx')
    idx = m.start()
    matches.append([idx, fnc, msg, ctx])
print(matches)
```

I have the feeling that `re` alone isn't capable to do exactly what I am looking for but any suggestion/solution which gets closer is more than welcome.

Comment: As there is no 'ctx' group defined in the regex, it looks to me this is more a regex pattern issue than a python issue. Correct?

Comment: @Jerome Yes, that's the question about. The reason that there isn't a ctx group defined is because I haven't found a way to add it to produce the desired results.

Comment: I don't think you can do this with regex (I'm pretty sure). I think the only way to go is to parse the JavaScript code as JavaScript and inspect the parse tree. Have a look at something like `antlr4`, which has a Python library and can parse JavaScript code.